# how to link mysql data base with my localhost website

Tags: php, html, mysql, web, localhost

I am beginner with creating websites

I have already created a website by html and ccs
and also i created the database by my sql queries

Now still link the database with my website in xampp server

But I have no idea how to do it

I search google i found one explanation that told me to create db_connection.php file in htdocs where my website files located and import my database file to myphp admin

I did all these steps

I don't know what is the next step
should i write any codes in each page code of my website or not

I hope someone help me

I will really thankful for him/her

Comment: Please add your reference link (google explanation) and sample code.

Comment: Do you want to connect your hosted website with your local DB?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take time and visit [SO Asking Help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and must read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in the same. Also, see [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/198362/378417)

Answer (score 0):

In your db_connection.php you should write

```
$dbServername = "localhost"; //if you use xampp, it will be localhost
$dbUsername = "yourUsername"; //standart login is root
$dbPassword = "yourPassword"; //standart password is none, so leave it empty
$dbName = "yourDbName"; //place your db name here

$conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername, $dbUsername, $dbPassword, $dbName);
```

Now you are connected to your db. Include this file where you need to perform query's.